# Assigning values to multiple variables in an object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Is there a way when assigning points, that the code doesn't repeat itself so much?** Also the code isn't finished yet there is more checking to be done. When you first assign health point you can assign more than specified, and then it asks you to assign points even when there is none left to assign, and the "Points remaining" goes to negative until the while loop checks, but this is something i will try to fix myself.

```
class Player:
     def __init__(self, name, health, strength, defence, luck):
         self.name = name
         self.health = health
         self.strength = strength
         self.defence = defence
         self.luck = luck

def playerSetup():
     optio = Player

     name = input(colored("\nWhat is your name soldier? ", "yellow"))
     optio.name = name  


while points > 0:   

    health = int(input("\nType in your Health: "))
    if points > 0:
        optio.health =  health + optio.health
        points = points - optio.health
        print("Points remaining: ", points)

    strength = int(input("\nType in your Strength: "))
    if points > 0:
        optio.strength = optio.strength + strength
        points = points - optio.strength
        print("Points remaining: ", points)

    defence = int(input("\nType in your Defence: "))
    if points > 0:
        optio.defence = optio.defence + defence
        points = points - optio.defence
        print("Points remaining: ", points)

    luck = int(input("\nType in your Luck: "))
    if points > 0:
        optio.luck = optio.luck + luck
        points = points - optio.luck
        print("Points remaining: ", points)
```

Comment: What is `optio` here?

Comment: Is that `while` loop supposed to be part of the `__init__` method? Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `code` def playerSetup():
    optio = Player

    name = input(colored("\nWhat is your name soldier? ", "yellow"))
    optio.name = name  `code`

Comment: @Jakob Please [edit] code into your question; don’t paste it in a comment.

Comment: But meanwhile, `optio = Player` doesn’t create a Player instance, it just makes `optio` into a name for the Player class object itself, which isn’t useful. To construct an instance, you have to _call_ the class. And, the way you’ve written your `__init__` method, you can’t do that until after you have all the values to pass in.

Comment: Here is a GitHub repo with all the code [link](https://github.com/iakobj/TestProject)

Comment: Also, that indentation doesn’t make any sense. Are you sure the `while` loop isn’t supposed to be part of that `playerSetup` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to cut down on code repetition is to define a list of attribute names and use `setattr()` to assign them:

```
for attribute in ['health', 'strength', 'defence', 'luck']:
    if points > 0:
        amount = int(input('Type in your %s: ' % attribute))
        setattr(optio, attribute, amount)
        points = points - amount
    else:
        print('No points left for %s' % attribute)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was something i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to refactor something as a function is to figure out what values you need to pass in, and what values you need to return:

```
def spendattr(name, value, points):
    spent = int(input(f"\nType in your {name}: ")
    if points > 0:
        value = value + spent
        points = points - spent
    print("Points remaining: ", points)
    return value, points
```

Then calling it is usually a one-liner:

```
while points > 0:
    optio.health, points = spendattr('Health', optio.health, points)
    optio.strength, points = spendattr('Strength', optio.strength, points)
    … etc.
```

Now it should be easier to improve whatever you need to improve, because you only have to write it in one place instead of four.

There is still a bit of repetition—you have to type `health` twice and `Health` once, etc.—but not enough to invite copypaste bugs.

---

If you want to eliminate even that, I think it would be easier to build up a dict of values, and then construct the Player object out of that dict.

Assuming you’re using Python 3.7+ or CPython 3.6, so we can rely on dicts being ordered:

```
def spendattr(name, attrs, points):
    spent = int(input(f"\nType in your {name.title()}: ")
    if points > 0:
        attts[name] = attrs[name] + spent
        points = points - spent
    print("Points remaining: ", points)
    return points

attrs = {'health':0, 'strength':0, …}
while points > 0:
    for attr in attrs:
        points = spendattr(name, attrs, points)
player = Player(name=playername, **attrs)
```